# Fork and multiprocessing

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    int p;
    p = fork();
    if (fork()==0) {
        if (execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "foo", 0) == -1) {
            fork();
        }
        printf("bar\n");
    }
    else {
        if (p!=0) execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "baz", 0);
        }
}
```

Why does this program print baz foo foo and not bar foo baz? At p=fork() a child i created.The parent goes to else{} and prints baz. Then in the line if(fork()==0) a grandchild is created. So the grandchild enters and print foo. Should it also print bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exec*` functions *replaces* the process with the new program, so the code after the `execl` call you do never runs.

Comment: and you run fork() twice, (p=fork() and fork()==0) hence two foo's

Comment: @ThemisMavridis The operating system loads the program _into_ your process, so your program no longer exists only the newly loaded program.